# Start MongoDB from within a Grunt task

Tags: mongodb, shell, automation, gruntjs

Is it possible to start MongoDB from within a Grunt task?  Basically when I'm running my development environment with `grunt server` I want it to start up the MongoDB server as well possibly by running `mongod`.

Comment: Sorry @SindreSorhus, I haven't come back to working through this since. The answer is now accepted.

Comment: grunt-shell is blocking, so the command hangs the rest of the build steps.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use [grunt-shell](https://github.com/sindresorhus/grunt-shell) to run the command:

```
grunt.initConfig({
    shell: {
        mongo: {
            command: 'mongod'
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 39):

You can use [grunt-shell-spawn](https://github.com/cri5ti/grunt-shell-spawn) to do this. The previous answer recommends grunt-shell, which runs synchronously on the main process - blocking execution of other tasks.

```
shell: {
    mongo: {
        command: 'mongod',
        options: {
            async: true
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 22):

To add to JJJ's answer, using [grunt-shell-spawn](https://github.com/cri5ti/grunt-shell-spawn) if you want to make sure each project has it's own mongodb instance with it's own data you would do this:

```
shell: {
    mongodb: {
        command: 'mongod --dbpath ./data/db',
        options: {
            async: true,
            stdout: false,
            stderr: true,
            failOnError: true,
            execOptions: {
                cwd: '.'
            }
        }
    }
},
```

The example also prints out only errors.

You would then just add `shell:mongodb` to your `grunt server` task list (preferably the first task), add `data` to your `.gitignore` (assuming you're using git) and you're good to go.

Comment: With the default mongo setup I have, I used the db path `/data/db` without the initial directory mark. Other than that this is a great addition to JJJ's already great answer.